# how to see all AssertionError messages in testNG soft assert comparing List <String>

Tags: java, testng, assert

I am trying to compare `List<String> A` and `List<String> B` with `softAssert.assertEquals (A, B, "Message");` in testng.

It gives me the **first** comparison error Message:

> Lists differ at element [2]: Sanders != Adler expected [Sanders] but found [Adler]

but there are other comparison errors - how can I see all of them?

I know how to compare them without testNG - the requirement is to use TestNG.

Comment: How big are you lists?  You can always output the contents as part of your "message".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to write your own `SoftAssert`.

`SoftAssert` in TestNG uses `assertEquals()` from `Assertions` and just catch all exception to throw them after `assertAll()`. `assertEquals()` just iterates through list and finds first error.

If you have to use only TestNG assertions it would be better to iterate through lists manually and make soft assert for each element. See example here [SoftAssertComparingList.java](https://github.com/RocketRaccoon/TestNG-Examples/blob/master/src/test/java/SoftAssertComparingList.java)

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! But what about when these lists have different length - can we have a message like "first (or second) list has additional members "aaa", "bbb","ccc" ?

Comment: I have updated the example. But you should think first - is it ok that your lists has different size? May be you have to add assertion to check size before continue.

Comment: Thank you again and I even know how to say bolshoe spasibo! I did it differently, but I like your code! I did add assertion to check the size. Now - may be you will help me with reading the parameters from Excel for the tests - I know how to read Excel with loops in java, but in Test NG - I need to read a method name from Excel and choose the appropriate tests and pass different parameters to that tests if they are chosen in Excel - have y in certain column. I think I need to read a line in @BeforeSuite  - but how to return to next row and continue? Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your excel file?

Comment: 2 sheets - sheet GetFiles with ExpResFile path, Delimiter, ActResFile path, Delimiter columns; sheet TC with Number, TestCase, Parameter, Include, Column, Method. from

Comment: From GetFiles I have to read paths for files to compare and their delimiters; from TC - TC number, TestCase content, Parameter - % for dispersion - what difference in column data is allowed, Column - which columns we are going to compare from that files -1,2,etc, Method - equal or not null or dispersion - compare values of columns with parameter difference allowed. Method equal  you already helped me to write, correct :)

Comment: I missed Include - execute this TC if Include=touppercase("y").

Comment: I am trying to write a simple dataprovider following examples from web - for some reason it says ClassNotfoundException - do you know why can it be?

Comment: I suppose the best way would be close that question and move to my github repo. Please raise an issue there with description and I will try to help you with code examples.